# Cant fit TabPanel into Window with ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Window in ExtJs 3.4 app:

```
         x = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'myWindow', 
        layout: 'fit',
        title:'Информация БДОН',
        autoScroll:false,
        width:600,
        autoLoad : {  
            url : url_servlet+"form.jsp?bdon=1&ss="+str,                                        
            scripts: true  
        }
    })
    x.show();
```

And load contant to this window with `autoLoad` from form.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function highlightWindow() {
            var win = Ext.getCmp('myWindow');  
            var winBody= win.body;  
            winBody.highlight();

            var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
                type:'tabpanel',
                deferredRender: false,
                activeTab: 0,
                bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
                autoScroll: false,
                layoutOnTabChange: true,
                height:400,
                hideMode: 'offsets',

                items: [searchform,zemform,reallyform,docform,podform]
            });
            tabs.render(winBody);
        }
        highlightWindow.defer(1000);
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Where `searchform,zemform,reallyform,docform,podform` its FromPanels into a TabPanel. Every thind works fine but looks ugly:

[image]

You see that form not fit in window even if i use `layout:'fit'`.
Whats wrong in here?

Comment: You didn't read the docs, about render/renderTo: `Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager to render and manage its child items.`

Comment: Maybe it is the `height` from the tabpanel? Can you look if it is padding or margin with debug tools?

Comment: `tabs.render(winBody);` = `win.add(tabs)`;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fit layout for your formpanel.